# A game of singletons

Tags: co.combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Alice and Bob play the following zero-sum game, parametrized by two integers $m$ and $k$:

- Alice picks $m$ sets, each of which has $k$ items.
- Bob colors some items in green.
- Bob's score is the number of *distinct singletons*, where a singleton is defined as a green item contained in a set in which all other $k-1$ items are uncolored (if there are several different sets with the same single green item, only one is counted towards Bob's score).

**What is the highest score Bob can guarantee to himself, as a function of $m$ and $k$?**

- A lower bound is $\Omega(m^{1/k})$. *Proof.* Suppose Bob colors each item in the world (=the union of all Alice's sets) with probability $p$, independently of the others. The probability of each item to be a singleton is: $p\cdot(1-p)^{k-1}$;    this is maximized when $p=1/k$, and the maximum is at least $1/(e\cdot k)$. Then, the expected number of singletons is at least $n/(e\cdot k)$, where $n$ is the world size.    Therefore, Bob can always guarantee to himself a score in $\Omega(n/k)$.
  The number of sets $m$ is at most ${n \choose k}$ which is at most $(n\cdot e/k)^k$, so  $n \in \Omega(k\cdot m^{1/k})$,   so Bob's score is in $\Omega(m^{1/k})$.
- An upper bound is $O(k\cdot m^{1/k})$. *Proof.* Alice can choose $n$ such that $m={n \choose k}$, and select all $k$-element subsets of the integers   $1,\ldots,n$. Bob can get at most $n$ singletons. In fact he can get exactly $n-k+1$ singletons, by coloring all items except $1,...,k-1$.
  So Bob's score is in $O(n) = O(k\cdot m^{1/k})$.

So what is the correct expression? Can Alice always force Bob to get at most $O(m^{1/k})$? Or can Bob always get at least $\Omega(k\cdot m^{1/k})$?

Comment: Note: it is important that Bob's score is a function of $m$ and $k$, and not of the world size $n$.  If Bob's score were a function of $n$ and $k$, then both the upper and lower bounds would have been $n/k$:  lower bound same as above, and upper bound when Alice selects $n/k$ disjoint sets.

Comment: Clarification in case anybody read this the same way as me: we are counting green points with some property, not $k$-sets containing exactly one green point.

Comment: @BenBarber yes, if there are several different sets with the same single green item, only one is counted towards Bob's score. Added clarification.

Comment: Doesn't the probability for an item $x$ to be a singleton depend on the number $m_x$ of sets (chosen by Alice) that contain it? In each of these, it has a probability of $p(1-p)^{k-1}$ of 'attaining singleton status through this set'. The chance of being singleton should be higher than that (depending on the structure of the sets chosen by Alice, though).

Comment: @monkeymaths yes, you are right, this is only a lower bound. Maybe the same probabilistic algorithm can be better analyzed to give a better lower bound.

Comment: How do you define $\Omega$?

Comment: @WlodAA I had in mind the definition common in computer science (of Knuth), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation

Answer (score 2):

None of those seems correct if $k\ge \log m$. Consider your construction described for the upper bound, except that we make divide all elements into $s$ groups of size $\frac kt$, and Alice picks the $\binom st$ sets that contain exactly $t$ groups. Then, as you've mentioned, Bob's score is at most $s$, since he can win at most one singleton per group. In fact, Bob's score is $s-t+1$, which is independent of $k$. I'm not sure what choice of $s$ and $t$ optimizes this, but the best score should be around $\log m$, provided that $k\ge \log m$. Of course, this leaves the problem open and interesting for small $k$.

Comment: If $k\geq \log_2{m}$, then $m^{1/k}\leq 2$, so my upper bound gives $O(k)$. So your construction improves this to $O(\min(k,\log{m}))$, right?

Comment: @Erel I think so.

Comment: This construction doesn't actually improve on Erel's construction. Take $m= { s \choose t}$ for some $t \leq k$. Let $n$ be so that $n-k = s-t$, in particular, $n \geq s$. Then we have ${ s\choose t} = { s  \choose s-t} = { s \choose n-k} \leq {n \choose n-k} = {n \choose k}$ so Erel's construction gets the same upper bound with a larger $m$. Instead, your improvement comes from a better estimate of the inverse binomial function in this range.

Comment: @Will I thought $m$ and $k$ were both parameters in which we try to optimize.

Comment: @WillSawin Where did your answer go? I thought it was (almost) correct.

Answer (score 1):

Alice can select $\ m:=2\cdot n\ $ sets, each having $\ k:=2^{n-1}\ $ elements, in such a way that poor Bob can score at the most $\ n\ $ green singletons and not more ($\ n=2\ 3 \cdots$).

Thus Bob's best score $\ B(m\ k)\ $ for even $\ m\ $ and
$\ k=2^{m/2}\ $ is reduced by Alice to $\ m/2.$